# What is the difference between declaring a package and importing a package in a Modelica model?

Tags: import, package, modelica

I could declare a package or import a package in Modelica models, but I am not sure if there is any difference between them, I tried the following code, both of them work fine.
My question is :
Is there anything I should pay attention to when using these two methods?

```
partial model A
  package SI1=Modelica.SIunits;
  import SI2=Modelica.SIunits;
  SI1.Voltage u1;
  SI2.Voltage u2;
end A;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing two fundamentally different things here, which both work for this case:

`package SI1=Modelica.SIunits;` is called a short class definition.
You create a new package named `SI1`, which inherits everything from `Modelica.SIunits`.

Short class definitions are basically the same as writing

```
package SI1
  extends Modelica.SIunits;
end SI1;
```

See chapter [4.5.1 Short Class Definitions](https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch4.html#short-class-definitions) in the Modelica spec for details.

`import SI2=Modelica.SIunits` on the other hand simply influences where the Modelica tool looks for class definitions - so no new class is defined here. The chapter [13.2.1.1 Lookup of Imported Names](https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch4.html#slookup-of-imported-names) explains that in the Modelica spec.

If you just want to use the package, import it. That's what `import` was designed for. Declaring a new package only makes sense if you want to add functionality or change anything (which is very limited though, if you are using the short class definition).

Answer (score 1):

Only the import clause seems to trigger the lookup on a package that is not already loaded. Using for example the Modelica_LinearSystems2 library:

1. import: it checks, and Modelica_LinearSystems2 is loaded

```
    partial model A
    import ls2=Modelica_LinearSystems2;
    end A;
```

2. package: it checks, but Modelica_LinearSystems2 is not loaded

```
  partial model B
  package ls=Modelica_LinearSystems2;
  end B;
```

I guess that can break your models if not all of their dependencies are loaded when trying to simulate.

It is nevertheless interesting to see how Dymola (or even Modelica, since pedantic check doesn't throw any error) does not seem to care much about the use of package instead of import, when it comes to packages already loaded. I wasn't expecting the following model to work:

```
  model C
    package SI1=Modelica.SIunits;
    SI1.Voltage u1;
    parameter SI1.Current R=1;
  equation 
    u1=2*R;
  end C;
```

It turns out that even auto-completion (Ctrl+Space) works:

[image]